I wish I were taller. VS. I wish I was taller

I wish I were taller. VS. I wish I was taller.

What's the difference between them?

Both of these are commonly said and written by native speakers. Technically, were is correct. Here is why it's confusing and why that is the preferred answer:
The case for was
Was is usually used with singular subjects (I, he, it, etc.), whereas were is used with plural subjects (we, they, etc.) and with you, which always takes plural verbs. Because of this, native speakers frequently follow that general rule and say I wish I was taller, since the subject I is singular.
The case for were
To be is a special verb, and were is a special conjugation of it. In addition to its normal role, it also is the go-to verb when speaking in the past subjunctive. (The subjunctive is all about expressing wishes and hopes.)
Specifically when talking about things we wish were true, it is grammatically correct to use were.
Here is an article about this exact question.
Here is an article with more information about the subjunctive.

"Was" is just as grammatically correct as "were". Nowadays, we call the ill-named past subjunctive the "Irrealis".

@BillJ Interesting! Do you have a source I could look at which talks about that?

This may help: link
